# need to perform multi-column join on a dataframe with alook-up dataframe

Tags: dataframe, join, pyspark

I have two dataframes like so

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
| c1| c2| c3| c4| c5|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  2|  3|  4|
|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9|
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

```
+---+---+
|key|val|
+---+---+
|  0|  A|
|  1|  B|
|  2|  C|
|  3|  D|
|  4|  E|
|  5|  F|
|  6|  G|
|  7|  H|
|  8|  I|
|  9|  J|
+---+---+
```

I want to lookup each column on df1 with the equivalent key in df2 and return the lookup val from df2 for each.

Here is the code to produce the two input dataframes

```
df1 = sc.parallelize([('0','1','2','3','4',), ('5','6','7','8','9',)]).toDF(['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5'])
df1.show()
df2 = sc.parallelize([('0','A',), ('1','B', ),('2','C', ),('3','D', ),('4','E',),\
                     ('5','F',), ('6','G', ),('7','H', ),('8','I', ),('9','J',)]).toDF(['key','val'])
df2.show()


I want to join the above to produce the following

+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| c1| c2| c3| c4| c5|lu1|lu2|lu3|lu4|lu5|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  2|  3|  4|A  |B  |C  |D  |E  |
|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9|F  |G  |H  |I  |J  |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+--+----+
```

I can get it to work for a single column like so but I'm not sure how to extend it to all columns

```
df1.join(df2, df1.c1 == df2.key).select('c1','val').show()

+---+---+
| c1|val|
+---+---+
|  0|  A|
|  5|  F|
+---+---+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just chain the join:

```
df1
    .join(df2, on=df1.c1 == df2.key, how='left')
    .withColumnRenamed('val', 'lu1') \
    .join(df2, on=df1.c2 == df2.key, how='left) \
    .withColumnRenamed('val', 'lu2') \
    .etc
```

You can even do it in a loop, but don't do it with too many columns:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df = df1
for i in range(1, 6):
    df = df \
        .join(df2.alias(str(i)), on=f.col('c{}'.format(i)) == f.col("{}.key".format(i)), how='left') \
        .withColumnRenamed('val', 'lu{}'.format(i))

df \
    .select('c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'lu1', 'lu2', 'lu3', 'lu4', 'lu5') \
    .show()
```

**output**

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| c1| c2| c3| c4| c5|lu1|lu2|lu3|lu4|lu5|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9|  F|  G|  H|  I|  J|
|  0|  1|  2|  3|  4|  A|  B|  C|  D|  E|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. The loop code you showed  gave me this error though                              

name 'f' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
NameError: name 'f' is not defined

Comment: I also received a "u'Detected implicit cartesian product for INNER join between logical plans" error when trying your forst method. Could you show me the output of your methods using the data I supplied in my question?

Comment: i was a bit too fast, dont have spark env here. updated answer.

Comment: Sorry Laurens neither of your answers worked for me. The INNER join error persists even with you changed code for method 1

Comment: spun up a databricks and removed quite a few typo's XD go for it, it runs now

Comment: Brilliant Laurens, your lookup loop now works a treat. Many thanks.